# How to calculate any date from current day, day in week, month and year?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, puzzle

I am implementing Calendar View for my iOS application. I am using `Date` structure for calculating date. But, manually I am stuck with following things. I need formulae for calculation between days depends upon current date.

For Example:

Need to find following categorise depends upon the current date.

Where current date,

> let date = 07
>
> let month = 11
>
> let weekDay = 03 (Tuesday)
>
> let year = 2017

Find:

1. Week day of this month where date is 01.
2. Week day of last month end date and start date.
3. Week day of current date on 2018.

Please give me the answer if you know at least one of 3 questions.

Comment: Have you looked at the older questions listed under "Related"? Some of them look very relevant.

Comment: @GerryMyerson , Yes bro... tried 3 hours, but stuck with these 3 parts.

Comment: Really? and you can't figure out what day of the week the 1st is, from knowing the 7th is a Tuesday?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, lol.. figured out just now bro... Thanks for this above comment.... may I need to delete this question? or Will I answer later?

Comment: If you don't think it's answered at one of those related questions, you can post an answer.

Comment: You might be interested in algorithms for converting Gegorian calendar dates to/from Julian day number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Converting_Gregorian_calendar_date_to_Julian_Day_Number

Comment: @awkward, Yes I am also trouble to find algorithms. Thanks bro I will try with that.

Comment: Why code this yourself? `NSDate` and related classes in Foundation (the `Date` structure in the Swift overlay) provides ways to do all of these calculations.

Comment: @amd , Thank you for that point bro. Why ,Because of learning bro. Actually my problem is easily solved by using `DateComponents` same as you said. I think need to follow algorithm awkward commented or need to read source of `Date` in swift.

Comment: It’s great that you want to learn how to do this yourself, but you led off your question with “I need to implement Calendar View on my iOS application,” which suggests that your priority is just getting it done.

Comment: @amd, oh, I did not mind that. I thought the word `formulae ` will not led off. I will edit it.